# Docker-compose using host environment variable

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to do the following in my docker-compose.yml

But I hit this warning?
`WARNING: The HOSTNAME variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string`

`environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: ${HOSTNAME}`

The HOSTNAME environment variable is obviously set on the host.

Answer (score 11):

You just need to export your environment variable to the `docker-compose` process. Try this instead:

```
$ export HOSTNAME
$ docker-compose up
```

Source: https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-compose-not-seeing-environment-variables-on-the-host/11837/2

Answer (score 4):

An error saying the variable is not set looks strange indeed.

I use host variables like this:

```
mycontainer:
  image: <repo>/<image>:${SERVICE_VERSION}
  environment:
    - DB_USER=${DB_USER}
    - DB_PASS=${DB_PASS}
```

Comment: No I guess it must be that I'm using HOSTNAME.

Comment: Ya so just tried HOST_IP and set this on the host machine first with `export HOST_IP=$(/sbin/ip route|awk '/default/ { print $3 }')` this works

Comment: I guess docker is stripping out HOSTNAME env variable

Comment: Docker is automatically setting some variables: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables However that does not explain why the HOSTNAME is stripped during compose.yml reading.